# Android Studio - Why emulator process killed when no skin chosen

Tags: android, android-studio

I used Android Studio before and setup buildin device (Pixel 3), I remove "Enable device frame" option for saving screen size.
All works fine.

Today I tried to setup a device with a new screen resolution (iPhone 11 Pro like - 1125x2436). I delete old Pixel 3 and created a new device, remove "Enable device frame" option, start. After progress bar appear the end, the emulator is closed and error appear:
"**The emulator process for AVD devicename was killed.**"
I trying some google, updated Studio, rebooted PC (Linux), created new devices, but nothing helped.

I tried chose "**Enable device frame**" option and pick a skin. After that emulator successfully started (!).

Can anybody explain why emulator not starting without skin? Can it be fixed somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed the issue.
For some strange reasons emulator launch without device frames after I changed screen resolution from 1125x2436 to 1126x2436.